# Add new icon and listener on the Map

Tags: android, osmdroid

how can i add an icon in the lower right corner, as that of GMaps, complete with a tap listener?

[image]

N.B. i don't want to add a marker with a GeoPoint!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This icon is called FloatingActionBar. Its a View where you can add an OnClickListener like on a button. You can simply use this with a FrameLayout in your layout.

Comment: maybe Floating Action Button, thanks. But i'm not sure is what i want, i didn't want to edit layout, but use some overlay of osmdroid, if exists.